# Delete unordered list in HTML with Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Basically, the task I needed to perform is to delete the whole "agent" array by using the `removeChild()` function, but it needs the `<ul>` id, according to what I read [here][1].
After that, I need to replace the "agent" array with "freshagent" array and display it in an unordered list.

My problem is that I can't set the id for "ul" because I used the `createElement()` function.
Thus, I can't remove the "agent" array.

//old code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        </div>
        <script>
            var agents = [
                "Dion" ,
                "Elisa" ,
                "Selena" ,
                "Shauna" ,
                "Rodger"
            ];
            var freshAgents = [
                "Gray",
                "Shivani",
                "Brainne",
                "Jason",
                "FChad"
            ];
            var i = 0;
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.setAttribute("id","aList");
            for (i in agents){
                var list = document.createElement('li');
                var node = document.createTextNode(agents[i]);
                list.appendChild(node);
                ul.appendChild(list);
            }
            rList = document.getElementById("aList");
            if (rList.hasChildNodes()){
                for(i in agents){
                    rList.removeChild(rList.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }

            var finalList = agents.concat(freshAgents);

            for (i in finalList){
                var list = document.createElement('li');
                list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalList[i]));
                ul.appendChild(list);
            }

            document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(ul);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

//new code(working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">

</div>



<script>

var agents = ["Dion" ,"Elisa" , "Selena", "Shauna", "Rodger"];

var freshAgents = ["Gray", "Shivani", "Brainne", "Jason","FChad"];

var i = 0;

var ul = document.createElement('ul');


for (i in agents){

    var list = document.createElement('li');

    var node = document.createTextNode(agents[i]);

    list.appendChild(node);

    ul.appendChild(list);

    }


var rList = document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(ul);


do{

    rList.removeChild(rList.childNodes[0]);


}while(rList.hasChildNodes())



for (i in freshAgents){

    var list = document.createElement('li');

    list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(freshAgents[i]));

    ul.appendChild(list);

    }


</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: thank @user6003859 for editing my code

Comment: I had done some modification in the code. But I still not understand why it works? Can some body explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are going about it a really long way. I have tweaked your code somewhat to make it do what I think you are asking. I would do something different but it seems clear from your question that this is the way you want it.

```
var agents = ["Dion", "Elisa", "Selena", "Shauna", "Rodger"];
var freshAgents = ["Gray", "Shivani", "Brainne", "Jason", "FChad"];
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.id = "aList";// give it an ID
for (var i = 0; i < agents.length; i++) {
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var node = document.createTextNode(agents[i]);
  list.appendChild(node);
  ul.appendChild(list);
}
document.getElementById("wrapper")
  .appendChild(ul);
rList = document.getElementById("aList");//this is the same as ul variable declared above
if (rList.hasChildNodes()) {
    console.log(rList.childNodes);//lists the <LI>...<LI> nodes
  for (var i = 0; i < rList.childNodes.length; i++) {//Loop through the nodes not your agent array
    rList.removeChild(rList.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
var finalList = agents.concat(freshAgents);
for (var i = 0; i < finalList.length; i++) {
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalList[i]));
  ul.appendChild(list);
}
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rich_henderson/vxutrafL/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand much of your question, but based on this

> Problem: I can't set id for "ul" because of using createelement function. I can't remove "agent" array.

I assume you want to add an `id` to an element that was created with `document.createElement()`. You can do that like so:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'exampleID';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please input your code in a neat and legible manner, so that it is readable by everyone. I've formatted your code to the following:

```
var agents = ["Dion", "Elisa", "Selena", "Shauna", "Rodger"];
var freshAgents = ["Gray", "Shivani", "Brainne", "Jason", "FChad"];
var i = 0;

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.setAttribute("id", "aList");

for (i in agents) {
    var list = document.createElement('li');
    var node = document.createTextNode(agents[i]);
    list.appendChild(node);
    ul.appendChild(list); }

rList = document.getElementById("aList");

if (rList.hasChildNodes()) {
    for (i in agents) {
rList.removeChild(rList.childNodes[i]); 
    }
}

var finalList = agents.concat(freshAgents);
for (i in finalList) {
    var list = document.createElement('li');
    list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalList[i]));
    ul.appendChild(list); 
}

document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(ul);
```

Another tip: since you're referring your HTML, it's recommended that you provide that code as well. Again, it's not a necessity, but just etiquette.

As for setting the `id`, use:

```
var example = document.createElement('ul');
example.id = 'example_ID';
```

Comment: There is HTML in the pastebin, it's just a simple `<div id="wrapper"></div>`

Comment: @EvanKennedy The pastebin link was added after I'd begun writing this answer, so I didn't see that. Thanks! :)

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm new to stackflow, gotta find some time to figure it out, by the way, I have another problem, now I'm able to set up id, but the ul is null, and the error pop out is Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null. Is because of using create element?

Comment: @ZiSean if this solution is working for you, can you please confirm and mark it?